# How can I apply a filter to DC.js PieChart?

Tags: filter, pie-chart, dc.js

I've such type of data in my scv file :

```
Item_code, item_category, year,revenues
P51039F226EJ24,QQ,2015,0.200166805671393
P51039F226EJ24,QQ,2016,0.200176809567199
```

I need to create DC.js pieChart. In order to do this I have such code:

```
var pieChart = dc.pieChart('#pie');
    d3.csv("../assets/data.csv").then((data) => {
      var mycrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
      var categoryDimension = mycrossfilter.dimension(function (data) {
        return data['item_category'];
      });

      var categoryGroup = categoryDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.revenues; });
      pieChart
        .width(800)
        .height(300)
        .dimension(categoryDimension)
        .group(categoryGroup)
        .on('renderlet', function (chart) {
          chart.selectAll('rect').on('click', function (d) {
            console.log('click!', d);
          });
        });
```

How can I filter my pie by years?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking - do you mean that you want to 1. Display years as the slices of a pie chart? 2. Display only one year in a pie chart (and e.g. have multiple pie charts for multiple years)? 3. Filter all the charts by some year? There is ambiguity around the word "filter".

Comment: Btw you don’t want spaces in the header row of your csv- d3.csv will take this very literally.